# How can I calculate how much stronger a 16 dB gain is compared to 9 dB?

Tags: logarithms

I know that the decibel scale is logarithmic, so that a gain of 10dB would mean a 10x increase in power output. So 16dB would be approx 40x (?) and 9dB would be close to ten, perhaps 9x. So a gut feeling would say that a 16dB antenna would give me about 4-5x the power output of a 9dB antenna.

But how would I calculate this exactly?

Throwing around numbers like `log 16/log 9` or `log 16 - log 9` does not give me numbers anywhere near the right ballpark, it seems, so I could use a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be taking the logarithm of the dB values. The dB values are already logarithms, which is to say they are exponents (realizing that logarithms *are* exponents made logarithm arithmetic in general so much easier for me to remember and understand; $\log_x(ab) = \log_x(a) + \log_x(b)$ is not just derivable from $x^{m+n} = x^m\cdot x^n$, it's *exactly the same rule* written in two different ways, with $a = x^m, b = x^n$).

Thus we need to raise something to the powers of $9$ and $16$, and *then* we can take the ratio of the two. Alternatively, once we have the correct base, we can just raise that to the power of $16-9 = 7$ to get the same answer.

We need to find that base, and to help us we have a hint: An increase of $10$ in dB value means a ten-fold increase in power. So, if we call our base $x$, then for *any* dB value $a$, we have
$$
x^{a+10} = 10x^a\\
x^{a}\cdot x^{10} = 10x^a\\
x^{10} = 10\\
x = \sqrt[10]{10}
$$
So there you have it. The ratio of power output between the two is
$$
\frac{\sqrt[10]{10}^{16}}{\sqrt[10]{10}^{9}}\approx 5
$$
which is entirely within your ballpark.

Of course, actual dB values are calculated using a lot of constants here and there. I don't remember the exact formula, but I believe it could be a nice and easy exercise to show that they all cancel out in this problem and don't change the final result.

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It is worth remembering that a decibel is a deci-bel, that is a $\frac{1}{10}$ of a Bel.  Deci is a prefix alongside centi, mili, micro, etc but not used so often.

A Bel is a logarithmic measure of the ratio of two quantities.  Most commonly used with power but not necessarily only for power.  A ratio expressed in bels is the logarithm to base 10 of the ratio.  So, a ratio of 1Bel is $10$ times bigger, 2Bel is $10^2 = 100$ times bigger, etc.

This unit is often inconveniently big and the decibel is much more popular.  So, $10dB = 1B$.  This is why $10dB$ represents $10 \times$ bigger.  The two $10$s is sort of a coincidence and confusing because $20dB$ does not represent $20 \times$ bigger.  $20dB = 2B$ so it represents $10^2 = 100$ times bigger.

It is useful to remember that a ratio of $2$ in decibels is very close to $3dB$.  This is because $log_{10}(2) = .30103$.  This is very useful for quick estimates.  Hence $6dB$ is $4 \times$ bigger and $9dB$ is $8 \times$ bigger.

Comment: "The ratio in bels is the logarithm to base 10 of the ratio." I think you mean "The **difference** in bels is the logarithm to base 10 of the ratio."

Comment: @Arthur I was wondering on the best way to phrase that.  It's a rather odd unit and hard to describe.